# Detect array mutation

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer-1.0, mutation

I have made a simple proof-of-concept Polymer 1.0 app that demonstrates my problem: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yuzowijoqa/edit?html,js,output).

In my problem, I am using [array mutation methods](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-mutation) to alter the array, which contains the list of shopping items.

**However**, this doesn't seem to work as intended. I *do* get a change in `dom-repeat` and when printing the length of the array. *But* I **do not** get the change event when I am printing the array itself nor when I wrap it in a function.

In short, why does this work?

```
<p>Number of items: [[list.length]]</p>
```

And why does this **not** work?

```
<p>Items inline: [[list]]</p>    
<p>Observe function : [[_observe(list)]]</p>
```

**Also**, when I uncomment the following line (in the JSBin), things seem to work as indened. But I don't like it since it's a bit hackish.

```
app.notifyPath('list', app.list.slice());
```

I have stumbled upon the `slice()` fix by reading this issue: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2068

---

**EDIT**

So, after reviewing the comments, the answer to the question "Is this by design" is YES. The array itself doesn't change (since it's only a reference), but it's property *do* change. That's why the `slice()` forces the reload since it creates a shallow copy.

*However*, one could argue whether this is OK. Yes, the variable `list` does not change *per se*. But putting `[[list]]` in the HTML code actually triggers `toString()`. And result of that function *has* changed.

I guess I'm stuck with piggybacking the `length` property for now...

Comment: your jsbin sample works fine for me in chrome

Comment: if you wonder why observer not triggered, it just because link to the object it is just link, and it didn't changed, observe list.length and return list

Comment: or you can backup link to array in some var, notify without 2nd argument, and immediate notify with backedUp list, i not sure what faster, but this approach will not need to clone array, and more over it will not need deep clone in complex cases.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/horazuhelo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Other solution (in case when you change array value) could be to setup notifier object, value which will need to be changed every time you update array, you can't just watch whole array or any other object by properties or subproperties values, just because in general cases it would be very slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments the `notifyPath` and `slice` calls are creating a shallow copy of the array and assigning a different reference back to the `list` variable - triggering an update of the binding.  Without maintaining a separate *(watchable)* variable or messing around with object references, the only other workaround I can think of would be to piggy back on the `list.length` property instead of the list itself and pass that through some kind of *"formatting"* function.  ***e.g.***

```html
<p>Items inline: [[format(list.length)]]</p>
```

```js
app.format = function(){
    return app.list.toString();
};
```

[**» Fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/wusade/edit?html,js,output)

---

As pointed out by [@zb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815386/zb) you could expand on this and make the function reusable with any array by passing the relevant variable as an argument too:

```html
<p>Items inline: [[format(list, list.length)]]</p>
```

```js
app.format = function(list){
    return list.toString();
};
```

[**» Fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/mocagujapi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Ye I guess that would make it reusable.  It's a bit of a kludge regardless, the use-case is fairly limited.

Comment: @zb' and @Emissary I have updated my question a bit. But this probably doesn't change the solution for the problem: piggybacking the `length` property.